# Add Sub-items to Windows ContextMenu through Registry (No Shell)

Tags: c#, winforms, registry

I want to add a menu item to the Windows context menu and then add two sub menus for said menu.
I chose to *test* this for text files, trying to have both sub menus simply open the text files in notepad, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

**My menu is not added to the context menu at all** and I can't figure out what's the problem since all the registry keys are created just fine.

What am I missing?

PS: testing this on Windows 10, app running as admin.

I followed [this](https://www.askvg.com/add-cascading-menus-for-your-favorite-programs-in-windows-7-desktop-context-menu/) guide to create my code.

```
    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(".txt", true))
    {
        using (RegistryKey subkey = key.CreateSubKey(@"Shell\TestText"))
        {
            subkey.SetValue("MUIVerb", "TestText");
            subkey.SetValue("SubCommands", "process1;process2");
            subkey.SetValue("Icon", "notepad.exe");

            using (RegistryKey localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
            {
                using (RegistryKey shell = localMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell", true))
                {
                    using (RegistryKey one = shell.CreateSubKey("process1"))
                    {
                        one.SetValue("", "Process 1");
                        one.CreateSubKey("command");
                        one.OpenSubKey("command", true).SetValue("", "notepad.exe \" % 1\"");
                    }

                    using (RegistryKey two = shell.CreateSubKey("process2"))
                    {
                        two.SetValue("", "Process 2");
                        two.CreateSubKey("command");
                        two.OpenSubKey("command", true).SetValue("", "notepad.exe \" % 1\"");
                    }
                }
            }                    
        }
    }
```